# Xposed Abstract Methods and Interfaces

Tags: java, methods, interface, abstract, xposed

Is Xposed able to hook abstract methods and/or methods defined in interfaces? I am trying to hook a method defined in an interface with the usual findAndHookMethod, but it returns

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot hook interfaces: public abstract void com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock.MediaListView$OnItemPickListener.onItemPick(android.net.Uri,java.lang.String)
```

This is my method call:

```
findAndHookMethod("com.angrydoughnuts.android.alarmclock.MediaListView$OnItemPickListener", lpparam.classLoader, "onItemPick", "android.net.Uri", "java.lang.String", new XC_MethodHook() {
```

`OnItemPickListener` is the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Xposed is not able to hook abstract methods or interfaces. Only methods and constructors can be hooked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can try XposedBridge.hookAllMethods

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31017605)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot hook an interface, but you can hook every implementation if needed. You can find out what classes implement an interface in Android using resources such as http://grepcode.com/search/?query=google+android&entity=project