# Xposed can't hook getInstalledApplications

Tags: android, xposed

I wanted to hook getInstalledApplications and getInstalledPackages to monitor if the app use this method to get my appliactionlist.
My code:

```
XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(

                    android.content.pm.PackageManager.class.getName(),
                    lpparam.classLoader,
                    "getInstalledApplications",
                    new XC_MethodHook() {
                        @Override
                        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                            XposedBridge.log("getInstalledApplications()");
                            Log.d("HookLogin", "getInstalledApplications()");
                        }
                    });
```

And I got this error: `Xposed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.pm.PackageManager#getInstalledApplications()#exact`
Then I googled and found I should use `android.app.ApplicationPackageManager`,and I changed my code:

```
     XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(

                    "android.app.ApplicationPackageManager",
                    lpparam.classLoader,
                    "getInstalledPackages",
                    new XC_MethodHook() {
                        @Override
                        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                            XposedBridge.log("getInstalledPackages()");
                            Log.d("HookLogin", "getInstalledPackages()");
                        }
                    });
```

But i still got NoSuchMethodError,this time it is:

`Xposed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.ApplicationPackageManager#getInstalledApplications()#exact`

I'm confused now, how should I hook the method `getInstalledPackages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both code versions have one major problem:

Your hook can not work because you are trying to hook a method that does not exist: You are trying to hook the method `getInstalledApplications()` but that method does not exist, only the method `[getInstalledApplications(int)][1]` does exist and can be hooked.

You alerady notived that `android.content.pm.PackageManager` is an abstract class and the method `getInstalledApplications(int)` is abstract, too. As Xposed can not hook [abstract Methods and Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239046/xposed-abstract-methods-and-interfaces) you have to specify the class that that actually implements the method `getInstalledApplications(int)`.

The actual implementation of PackageManager is located in class [android.app.ApplicationPackageManager](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java) as you already found out.

Therefore the correct hooking code is:

```
XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(
    "android.app.ApplicationPackageManager",
    lpparam.classLoader,
    "getInstalledPackages", 
    int.class, // this line has been added as the getInstalledPackages method has one int parameter
    new XC_MethodHook() {
    @Override
    protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
        XposedBridge.log("getInstalledPackages()");
            Log.d("HookLogin", "getInstalledPackages()");
        }
    });
```